# Java Abstract Constructors Issues

Tags: java

I'm having issues with understanding how abstract constructors work. I am aware that an abstract super class is there to be like the back bone and all the sub classes have to have the methods placed in it but I don't understand the constructor side.

```
 public abstract class Animal{
           public String name;
           public int year_discovered; 
           public String population; 

 public Animal(String name, int year_discovered, String population){
           this.name = name;
           this.year_discovered = year_discovered;
           this.population = population; }
           }
```

Above is my super abstract class. Below is my subclass.

```
 public class Monkey extends Animal{
           public String type;
           public String color;

 public Monkey(String type, String color){
           super(name,year_discovered,population)
           this.type = type;
           this.color = color;}
               }
```

I get a error message that say's i'm trying to reference the supertype constructor before it is called.

Now the reason I am doing this is so I don't have to duplicate code for each different species. The code is just a quick example I made to try and help me put across my confusion. Thank you for any future replies.

Comment: where are your name,year_discovered,population fields in the child class or constructor? . you can't access those fields of the parent before it is created(i.e, before it's constructor is called.)

Comment: `i'm trying to reference the supertype constructor before it is called`---no, you're trying to reference the supertype *field* before the supertype constructor has completed.

Comment: Ah, I guess I have to put:public String name;
           public int year_discovered; 
           public String population; in the actual monkey class as well which saves no code at all hmm

Comment: @APD - you are passing those values to the super class.. you have to keep them somewhere (in the child class ) to pass right?

Comment: Now I have been shown some working examples I see where I have missed out declaring them in the monkey constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Monkey` class constructor should look like this:

```
 public Monkey(String name, int year_discovered, String population, String type, String color){
           super(name,year_discovered,population);
           this.type = type;
           this.color = color;
```

This way you won't have neither duplicate code nor compilation errors.

Comment: Ah I see. I knew in my head that I had to place the fields somewhere but it makes sense now. The super just references back to the superclass which already allocates what population etc.. are. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the Abstract class variables (`name,year_discovered,population`) before they were initialized in the `Monkey` class Constructor. Use like below

```
public Monkey(String name, int year_discovered, String population, 
                            String type, String color){
           super(name,year_discovered,population);
           this.type = type;
           this.color = color;
```

Answer (score 2):

And make your fields from the classes private not public.

Answer (score 1):

If the name and year_discovered are static for each sub-animal you can define the Monkey constructor as:

```
public Monkey(String type, String color){
       super("Monkey",1900,"100000");
       this.type = type;
       this.color = color;
}
```